# How can I get this entered span to update if the input is the same? it already changes if different

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following application searches the 3 lines (Ps) for whatever word you enter in the text area and click search for.

When the button is clicked and If the word is found, a span is then displayed to display how many times it was found and also highlights the P(s) it was found in

When the button is clicked and If the word is NOT found, a span is then displayed to display that it was not found

THIS WORKS!

**What does not work and what I cannot figure out is how I can have the count in the span update if the word is the same a second time entered and searched for**

for example if i enter Suns the first time I get 2 because it was found 2 times
if i enter it again I get the same result but I want it to update to 4 because it was found 2 times twice
if i enter a new word then it only shows me the new word and how many times it was found and I want it to only show the first word still.

```js
but1 =document.querySelector("#searchbutton");
but1.addEventListener('click',searchClick);

function searchClick() 
{
  var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchtext").value;
  var main = document.querySelector("#main");
  var mainParas = main.querySelectorAll(" p ");

  for (var i = 0; i < mainParas.length; i++) 
  {
    if (mainParas[i].textContent.indexOf(searchPhrase) >= 0)
    { 
      mainParas[i].className = "highlighted";
    }    // highlight 
    else 
    {
      mainParas[i].className = null;    // un-highlight
    }
  }
}



function count_search() 
{
  var allPs = "";
  var element = document.getElementById("output");
  element && element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.setAttribute("id", "output");
  document.body.appendChild(span);

  var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchtext").value;

  var mainParas = document.querySelectorAll("#main p");

  mainParas.forEach(el => allPs+= el.innerText);

  var regex = new RegExp(searchPhrase, "gi");
  var times = allPs.match(regex);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = times ? `How many times I searched for the word ${searchPhrase}: ${times.length}` : "No matches found";
}
```

```css
/* A style for paragraphs that have been highlighted from a search. */

 .highlighted {
background-color: yellow;
border: 1px dashed #666600;
font-weight: bold;
}

#output{
  position:relative; 
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src = "dom_2_alt.js" type = "text/javascript" defer> </script>
<link href= "outstyle.css"  type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />

</head>


<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, 
        Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>
    <p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an
    expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>
    <p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership 
    group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li> 
      <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
      <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
      <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>
    Page by Marty Stepp. <br />
    Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.
  </p>
  <hr />
  <div>
    Search for text:
    <input id="searchtext" type="text"  /> 
    <button id="searchbutton" onclick="count_search()"> Search
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to keep a cumulative count of all the search results, so your expected results looks like:

- "Suns" : 2
- "Suns", "Suns": 4
- "Arizona": 1
- "Suns", "Arizona": 3

And the way to start a new count would be to reload the page.

To make this happen, you have two options that I see, the first is to make a *global variable* of **times** that you are using in `function count_search()`

like this:

```
let times = 0;
function count_search() {
...
```

And your old `var times = allPs.match(regex);` will now have to be `times = times + allPs.match(regex).length;`

The second option would be to have a new `<span></span>` element for the result, then each time you run your program you can "read" what is the content of the span, convert it to a number (it will be a string) and then add the new *times* to that number and finally update the content of the span again.